# Inject Service into Directive AngularJS and data binding.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, directive

I created a Service that obtain data with $http and this data is stored in a variable of this Service, also I created a Directive that use the service to create a tag select with options, these options were obtained in the service, but this is my problem the data obtained never connect with directive.

Service and Directive:

```
angular.module('myModule'[])
    .factory('myService', ['$http', function($http){
        var listOptions = [];
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'urlToDataJson'
            }).then(function(resp){
                listOptions = resp.data
            })
        ;
        return {
            list: listOptions;
        }
   }]
   .directive('myDirective', ['myService', function(myService){
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<select ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in list"></select>',
        replace: true,
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope)
           $scope.list = MyService.list;
        ]
   }])
;
```

with the Chrome's DevTool I can see data is updated after $http runs, but the data not shown in the options.

The code above is an example that I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$http` call returns a promise object. Wrap the `$http` call in a function and return the promise object, then, in your directive, invoke this function and resolve the promise object and get the data.

Specifically,

```
getData(){
  return $http({
       method: 'GET',
       url: 'urlToDataJson'
       }).then(function(resp){
            listOptions = resp.data
   ); // this returns a promise
}
```

And then in your directive, resolve the promise like so:

```
MyService.getData().then(function(data){
   console.log(data); // <-- this is how you access the result of your $http call
});
```

Comment: I'll try to do that, but why works like that? I understand that there is an asynchronous call, but the result is assigned to a variable. Can you explain me a little bit?

Comment: You don't know when the http call will finish. If you were to do this without a promise, listOptions will be undefined, because of the asynchronous nature of JavaScript. Without a promise, you are trying to assign listOption's value BEFORE the http call had a chance to finish.

Comment: Now I have a doub, what's up when I use this directive into ng-repeat, there will be multiple request? or what's up when the data are updated in the server?. Thank You!

Comment: You can check the Network tab of your browser to see if it makes multiple requests. Typically, the directive's controller is instantiated for every occurrence of the directive on the page. So, if you have 4 instances of the directives on the page, there will be 4 corresponding controller instances and yes, 4 separate `$http` requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this also ,

```
return $q(function (resolve, reject) {

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'urlToDataJson'
        }).then(function(resp){
            $scope.responseDate = resp.data;
            resolve(responseData);
        });
});
```